# What is a reasonable procedure for figuring where a certain line of code on a wordpress site comes from?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a specific example for this question, but the question itself is more general. In the example, a wordpress site has a line of code, in the header:

```
<script src="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfld_DuR5.js" async=""></script>
```

Where should one look to figure out what plugin/script/file is responsible for this line?

Answer (score 0):

Search for part or all of the string in your site's source using your favorite editor's "Find in Project" feature. There aren't that many occurrences of `vfld_DuR5` in WP...